# How can I get my data back to my pc?

Tags: data-recovery

I use android. Recently I've found a problem.. I can see all the files and folders in my mobile phone.. But when I connect it to my pc to copy the files or folders to the pc I find that ***The folder is empty***. But the size is 1.7GB. I can't see the files in my phone connecting with the pc. I check that the hidden files are visible in my pc. I am using Windows 7 ultimate..

Comment: Try this: When you are connecting your phone to PC, check if the phone is unlocked. I face similar issue when the phone is unlocked. Also while accessing phone from PC close any file manager app that is opened on your phone.

Comment: I don't find such kind of circumstances...

Answer (score 0):

Since Android 4.0, the connection standard that is used to connect your phone to your computer is MTP. To be able to see the files on your mobile from your computer when they are connected you will need to make sure you have the correct USB driver for your phone and also that the phone is unlocked.